# Editing posts in reviewing queue

Tags: bug, review, edits

I'm reviewing posts in the "First Post" queue and when I have "too many edits pending" instead of showing this message when I click on "edit" it just goes to the top of the page.

But if I try to edit a post (the same one that I was looking up in the queue or another one) outside the queue I do get the error message, that's how I discovered why it was not taking me to the editor.

Here is what I see when trying to edit outside the queue:

[image]

When I'm on the queue it just takes me to the top of the post, so there is nothing I can show for that behavior.